# Xpages: Can a custom control have a variable number of facets?

Tags: xpages

I am still struggling with this.

I have a cc Panel with properties to control some attributes of the panel. There is an editable area in the middle of the panel.

I also have several cc Bootstrap reusable controls.

My problem is connecting the two. I want to have a custom control that I could drop in the panels editable area, that would allow me to select the number of rows and column. So I drop the cc in the editable area and there are two properties, rows and columns. So 3 rows and 2 columns would make a bootstrap grid of 3 rows with 2 columns, with an editable area in each cell.

I have worked with the suggestion at the end of this thread, using the Design Definition but it just doesn't work.

Can someone give me some insight into this problem?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xe:objectData
            saveObject="#{javascript:Test.save()}"
            var="Test">
            <xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:var Test = new com.scoular.model.Test();
var unid = context.getUrlParameter("key")

if (unid != "") {
    rwar.loadByUnid(unid);
    viewScope.put("readOnly","Yes");
} else {
    Test.create();
    viewScope.put("readOnly","No");
}
return Test;}]]></xe:this.createObject>
        </xe:objectData>
    </xp:this.data>
    <style>.row{ margin-top:40px; padding: 0 10px; } .clickable{ cursor: pointer; } .panel-heading span { margin-top: -20px; font-size: 15px; }</style>
    <xp:div
        id="${compositeData.panelID}"
        styleClass="${javascript:'panel ' + compositeData.panelStateClass}">
        <xp:this.style><![CDATA[${javascript://Declarations
    //String
    var sStyle:String = '';

//Check selections made for panelHeightFixed, panelHeightMax and panelEnableScroll
//Build style string accordingly

    //panelHeightMax
    if(compositeData.panelHeightMax != null && compositeData.panelHeightMax !=''){
        sStyle += 'max-height: ' + compositeData.panelHeightMax;

        //panelHeightFixed
        if(compositeData.panelHeightFixed == 'yes'){
            sStyle += ';height: ' + compositeData.panelHeightMax;
        }

        //panelEnableScroll
        if(compositeData.panelEnableScroll == 'yes'){
            sStyle += ';overflow-y: auto;'
        }
    }

 return sStyle}]]></xp:this.style>
        <xp:div
            id="divPanelHeading"
            styleClass="panel-heading"
            loaded="${compositeData.panelLayout eq 'header' || compositeData.panelLayout eq 'both'}">
            <xp:text
                escape="true"
                id="idTxtPanelTitleHTag"
                styleClass="panel-title"
                tagName="${compositeData.headerSettings.panelTitleType}"
                loaded="${compositeData.headerSettings.panelTitleType != 'none'}"
                value="${compositeData.headerSettings.panelTitle}" />
            <xp:span>
                <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"pull-right clickable"}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" />
            </xp:span>
            <xp:text
                escape="true"
                id="computedField1"
                value="#{ccompositeData.headerSettings.panelTitle}" />
            <xp:text
                escape="true"
                id="idTxtPanelTitle"
                loaded="${compositeData.headerSettings.panelTitleType == 'none'}"
                value="${compositeData.headerSettings.panelTitle}" />
        </xp:div>
        <xp:div
            id="divPanelBody"
            styleClass="panel-body">

            <xp:callback
                facetName="panelContentFacet"
                id="callbackPanelContent">
            <xc:cc_Common_Field_Text
                fieldName="textField"
                fieldLabel="Text"
                helpText="Text"
                placeholder="Text">
            </xc:cc_Common_Field_Text>
            </xp:callback>
        </xp:div>
        <xp:div
            id="divPanelFooter"
            loaded="${compositeData.panelLayout eq 'footer' || compositeData.panelLayout eq 'both'}"
            styleClass="panel-footer">
            <xp:callback
                facetName="panelFooterFacet"
                id="callbackPanelFooter" />
        </xp:div>
    </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

I have made a BootStrap panel custom control that has one facet. This makes it easy to control title text, footer text, and other properties of the panel

I have also made a simple "row" custom control that has two facets, a left and right. I can plunk down a field in each control and they will line up very well.

It looks like this.

[image]

[I need to tighten up the spacing a little].

What I want to be able to do is to put an arbitrary number of rows inside the panel customer control and then put fields in each facet.

I think I can make row custom controls with either 1,2, or 3 facets, and use whichever one I need.

But how can I get multiple facets in the panel custom control? Do I have to enter say 10 of them and just not use all of them, or is there a more dynamic way?

Comment: Very interesting question. Just a thought: how could you control the layout? For example, 2 facets can be any combination of grid columns (6/6, 4/8, 8/4, ..) For this reason I would stick to more controls with predefined facet count AND width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: you can have any number of facets - look at the Switch component of Extlib. What you really want is dynamic number of drop areas of your control. Thanks to [this great idea](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.sk/2010/01/xpages-using-powerful-design-definition.html) all you need is to write advanced design definition.

1. Define property for your control, let's say Columns with combo allowing 1, 2, or 3.
2. Write your design definition that it will conditionally hide excess facets.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
 <xp:div>
  <xp:callback
   facetName="column_1"
   id="callback1"
   xp:key="column_1">
  </xp:callback>
<% if(this.Columns>'1'){ %>
  <xp:callback
   facetName="column_2"
   id="callback2"
   xp:key="column_2">
  </xp:callback>
<% } %>
<% if(this.Columns>'2'){ %>
  <xp:callback
   facetName="column_3"
   id="callback3"
   xp:key="column_3">
  </xp:callback>
<% } %>
 </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Frantisek, this is really interesting. I had not known about the interaction between the design and the actual code, such that I can have 1-3 editable facets in this custom control. So I have a panel and I have a row. What I need to do I believe is change the panel so that I can select how many facets it has. So if I need 3 rows I would set a parm to 3 and I would have three place to drop my custom control, if 20 then I would have 20 places and so on. With the I believe I would have a really easy way to build panels/rows and then just pluck fields down.

Comment: Franitsek, I just can get this to work. I posted my example code into the original question. If you have any ideas I am all ears.

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler My answer works only to dynamically change number of drop areas of custom control. It does NOT cover anything about the content of such control. My advice: use more custom controls for one, two and three columns and nest them.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a more rambling answer elsewhere, but on reflection, it seems to me that this could be the solution you're looking for:

Create a BootstrapRow control like this:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:panel styleClass="row">
        <xp:callback facetName="columns" />
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

and give it a design definition like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
  <em>row</em>
  <xp:div style="width:100%">
    <xp:callback facetName="columns" />
  </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

Next, create a BootstrapColumn control:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:panel styleClass="#{compositeData.styleClass}">
        <xp:callback facetName="content"></xp:callback>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Design Definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
  <xp:span style="width:20%;">
    <em>col</em>
    <xp:div style="width:100%">
      <xp:callback facetName="content" />
    </xp:div>
  </xp:span>
</xp:view>
```

You might want to get fancy and have the span width compute based on the actual width so that the layout looks closer to what you will actually get. And obviously it will need a custom property for styleClass.

Put it all together and you get:

```
<xc:ccBSRow>
    <xp:panel xp:key="columns">
        <xc:ccBSColumn styleClass="col-xs-3">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:label value="Label" id="label2" xp:key="content"></xp:label>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:label value="Label" id="label1"></xp:label>
        </xc:ccBSColumn>
        <xc:ccBSColumn styleClass="col-xs-3">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText2" xp:key="content"></xp:inputText>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
        </xc:ccBSColumn>
        <xc:ccBSColumn styleClass="col-xs-3">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:label value="Label" id="label5" xp:key="content"></xp:label>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:label value="Label" id="label3"></xp:label>
        </xc:ccBSColumn>
        <xc:ccBSColumn styleClass="col-xs-3">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText3" xp:key="content"></xp:inputText>
            </xp:this.facets>
        </xc:ccBSColumn>
    </xp:panel>
</xc:ccBSRow>
```

There are plenty of other potential pitfalls you might run into, but I believe this at least provides a solution to what you've asked.